# What is the relation between homology groups of a manifold with boundary and space obtained after removing its boundary?

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, homology-cohomology, manifolds-with-boundary

I don't know much about homology theory, but the following question pops up in my mind and it may have some ambiguities.

Suppose $M$ is a finite-dimensional manifold with non-empty boundary $\partial (M)$. Now suppose $N= M-\partial(M)$ with induced topology from $M$. What is the relation between homology groups of $M$ and $N$?

Comment: I believe that by using a collaring of $M$, one can prove that $M$ and $N$ are homotopy equivalent.

Comment: Angina is right. The fact that the inclusion $N\to M$ is a homotopy-equivalence was discussed several times, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4151298/homotopy-equivalence-between-m-and-m-partial-m?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/211656/homotopy-type-of-the-manifold-minus-the-boundary?noredirect=1&lq=1). The hard part of the proof is the existence of a collar of $\partial M$ in $M$. For smooth manifolds that's easy, but for topological manifolds this is the hardest part of the proof.

Comment: With this in mind, the standard homology-theory result is that the inclusion map $N\to M$ induces an isomorphism of all homology groups (and all cohomology groups as well).

Comment: @MoisheKohan how does it behave in the PL category?

Comment: @Zest: How does what behave? Collar exists in all three categories (smooth, PL and Diff) if this is what you asked about.

Comment: Sorry, i phrased my question poorly. I was curious if the proof of the existence of a collar in the PL category is as easy as in the smooth category or if it's also rather hard as for topological manifolds.

Comment: @Zest It is even easier: Use the regular neighborhood of the boundary.

Comment: Thanks for your reply:-) I'm new to PL topology, thus the curiosity. I highly appreciate it.

Comment: @MoisheKohan: Thanks for links. Is this post equivalent to $H_i(M)=H_i(\overline{M})$ the closure of manifold?

Comment: I do not know what the "closure of a manifold" is since not every manifold is *tame*. The setting is that of a manifold with boundary (which you can call $\bar{M}$ if you wish) and its interior (which you can call $M$ if you like).

Comment: @MoisheKohan: Do you confirm the answer posted to this post?

Comment: This approach is reasonable but some work has to be done to make it into a proof.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have a sketch that $M \setminus \partial M \hookrightarrow M$ induces an equivalence in Homology, but I didn't check all the details. So please delete it if it's wrong. If someone works out the details, please post your answer, I'll delete mine then.

1. I think for every open subset $U \subset \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0} \times \mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ the inclusion $\mathbb{R}_{> 0} \times \mathbb{R}^{n-1} \hookrightarrow \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0} \times \mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ should induce a homotopy equivalence $U \cap (\mathbb{R}_{> 0} \times \mathbb{R}^{n-1}) \to U \cap (\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0} \times \mathbb{R}^{n-1})$.
2. There is an open cover $M = \bigcup_{i \in I} B_i$ such that each $B_i$ is isomorphic via a map $\phi$ an open subset $U_i$ of $\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0} \times \mathbb{R}^{n-1}$. Then $\phi$ sends $B_i \cap (M\setminus \partial M)$ to $U_i \cap (\mathbb{R}_{> 0} \times \mathbb{R}^{n-1})$ and $B_i \cap \partial M$ to $U_i \cap (\{ 0\} \times \mathbb{R}^{n-1})$.
3. Inductively over $k \in \mathbb{N}$ one may can show that $\iota: (B_{i_1} \cup \cdots \cup B_{i_k}) \cap (M \setminus \partial M) \hookrightarrow B_{i_1} \cup \cdots \cup B_{i_k}$ induces an isomorphism in homology using the Mayer Vietoris seqence
   $\require{AMScd}$
   \begin{CD}
   H_i((B_{i_1} \cup \cdots \cup B_{i_{k-1}}) \cap (M \setminus \partial M)) \oplus H_i(B_{i_k} \cap (M \setminus \partial M)) @>>> H_i((B_{i_1} \cup \cdots \cup B_{i_{k}}) \cap (M \setminus \partial M)) @>\partial>> H_{i-1}((B_{i_1} \cup \cdots \cup B_{i_{k-1}}) \cap (M \setminus \partial M) \cap B_{i_k}) @>>> H_{i-1}((B_{i_1} \cup \cdots \cup B_{i_{k-1}}) \cap (M \setminus \partial M)) \oplus H_{i-1}(B_{i_k} \cap (M \setminus \partial M))\\
   @V V H_i(\iota) \oplus H_i(\iota)  V @VV H_i(\iota)  V @VV H_i(\iota) V @V V H_{i-1}(\iota) \oplus H_{i-1}(\iota) V \\
   H_i(B_{i_1} \cup \cdots \cup B_{i_{k-1}}) \oplus H_i(B_{i_k}) @>>> H_i(B_{i_1} \cup \cdots \cup B_{i_{k}}) @>\partial>> H_{i-1}((B_{i_1} \cup \cdots \cup B_{i_{k-1}}) \cap B_{i_k})) @>>> H_{i-1}(B_{i_1} \cup \cdots \cup B_{i_{k-1}}) \oplus H_{i-1}(B_{i_k} )
   \end{CD}
   and 1. for the subsets of $B_{i_k}$ as well as the five lemma.
4. In singular homolgy every chain lies in a compact subspace covered by finitely many $B_i$'s. That's why 3. is enough to show that the inclusion $M \setminus \partial M \to M$ induces an equivalence in homology.