# Homotopy equivalence between $M$ and $M-\partial M$

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology, homotopy-theory, manifolds-with-boundary

One of my professors assigned this problem last semester and I recently looked back at it and am still a bit confused.
Let $M$ be a topological n manifold with boundary, which means, a second-countable, Hausdorff space such that for every $x \in M$, there is a neighborhood $U \ni x$ which is homeomorphic to either $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ or $\mathbb{R}^{n-1} \times [0,\infty)$. Also, assume that $\partial M$ has countable many components.

We have to prove that the inclusion $i : M - \partial M \to M$ is a homotopy equivalence.

I guess if one assumes compactness, you can use the Proposition 3.42 of Hatcher to get a collar neighborhood of $\delta M$ but I am not sure how to proceed from there, if this approach even works.

Comment: A proof is outlined [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/344104/collared-boundary-of-a-non-metrizable-manifold) on MO

Comment: The compactness assumption isn't necessary for collars, even in the topological category. See Morton Brown, *Locally flat imbeddings of topological manifolds* (Annals of Mathematics , Mar., 1962, Second Series, Vol. 75, No. 2 (Mar., 1962),
pp. 331-341).

Comment: The proof with collars is surely the best one, but you can also convince yourself it should be true because Poincare duality implies they have the same homology.

Comment: You have a tag "differential topology": For smooth manifolds, the existence of a collar is not hard at all and maybe your professor gave you the problem assuming that the manifold is smooth. For topological manifolds, see my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/703009/collar-neighbourhoods-for-topological-manifolds/703557#703557). Hatcher's proof can be adopted to apply to noncompact manifolds. Maybe this is what your professor had in mind.

Comment: One you know the existence of a collar, the question becomes a duplicate of [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/211656/homotopy-type-of-the-manifold-minus-the-boundary).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you have a collar neighborhood $N(\partial M) \approx \partial M \times [0,1)$ in your hands, you have to guess how to use it to define a homotopy inverse $g : M \to M - \partial M$.

But that's pretty natural. First let $k : [0,1) \to [.5,1)$ be a homeomorphism which is constant on $[.75,1)$. Outside of the collar neighborhood define $g$ to be the identity. Inside the collar neighborhood, define $g$ to be the composition the map
$$\partial M \times [0,1) \xrightarrow{\text{Id} \times k} \partial M \times [.5,1) \hookrightarrow \partial M \times (0,1)
$$

And finally you have to prove that the map $g : M \to M-\partial M$  is homotopic to the identity. But again that's done in pretty much the same way, starting with a homotopy from the composition
$$[0,1) \xrightarrow{k} [.5,1) \hookrightarrow [0,1)
$$
to the identity in such a way that the homotopy is stationary on $[.75,1)$.

Comment: Thanks, I just got the answer as well a little while back and was about to update my answer. Defining $g$ was the slightly tricky part.