# Morse Theory for sublevel sets with strict inequality

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, morse-theory

Let $M$ be a compact manifold and $f:M \to \mathbb{R}$ a Morse function. For a real number $s$, define
$$M^{\leq s}:=\{x \in M \ : \ f(x) \leq s\}.$$
In what follows, let $s<t$ be real numbers such that $[s,t]$ contains no critical value of $f$. The following theorem is well known from Morse Theory:

**Theorem.** $M^{\leq s}$ and $M^{\leq t}$ are diffeomorphic. Moreover, the natural inclusion $M^{\leq s} \hookrightarrow M^{\leq t}$ is a homotopy equivalence.

This has the following consequence:

**Corollary.** The homology groups $H_k(M^{\leq s})$ and $H_k(M^{\leq t})$, taken with coefficients in a field, are isomorphic for any $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. The corresponding isomorphism is induced by the natural inclusion $M^{\leq s} \hookrightarrow M^{\leq t}$.

My question: If we replace the weak ineqaulity "$\leq$" in the definition of the sublevel sets $M^{\leq s}$ and $M^{\leq t}$  by a strict one, "$<$", does the theorem or at least the corollary remain true?

Comment: I think your question is [duplicate of this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3337765/272127) somehow?

Comment: @C.F.G Thanks for the link. Not an exact duplicate but the questions seem to be related...

Comment: [Or this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/211656/272127)